# how do I create button like this in android with multiple text

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a button with multiple text inside the top and bottom of the button.  How do I create it?

A button can hold one text using andriod:text.  Can I add additional text within the button in a layout?

Comment: What does "a button with multiple text inside the top and bottom of the button" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean two lines, each with a different style ?

if so, use "[**fromHtml**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)" , and add line-breaks.